Does the absorption law for OR have two forms?

My text book states the above, and one of my homework problems asks me to simplify
x'yz +xz

I factored out a z to get
z(x'y+x)

But, this is the part where I am  confused, I asked chat gpt and double checked with an online boolean algebra calculator and with a truth table and found that the expressions
x'y+x = x+y

.
chatgpt and the online calculator referred to this as the absorption law, but I don't see it stated anywhere in my book. When I tried googling the definition of the absorption law I could only find the one stated in my textbook.
My question is, does the absorption law have two different forms for OR ? Or does this equivalence have a different name?
Oh, forgot to mention. I know that the distributive law for AND works in this case
z(x+x'y) = z((x+x')(x+y)) via distributive
         = z(1(x+y)) via Inverse OR
         = z(x+y) via identity AND

I think I know the answer, just wondering why chatgpt is saying this is the absorption law.

There is no 100% consistency and agreement on the use of these terms, and different sources use different names.  So, I can believe it when certain sources might say it is Absorption (though of course, you should never use ChatGPT as a reference as far as basic definitions and such go).
Personally, though, I don't consider the indicated equivalence $x' + xy = x + y$ as a form of Absorption, and I define Absorption just like your textbook does:
Absorption
$x + xy = x$
$x(x+y) = x$
To me, the idea of 'Absorption' is that the first first term completely absorbs the second term, and thus the second term can be removed completely.
So to me, this is quite different from the other equivalence, which I call 'Reduction':
Reduction
$x' + xy = x + y$
$x'(x+y) = x'y$
So here, the idea is that you reduce the second term to a smaller term in the context of the first term, but it doesn't get completely absorbed.
Reduction is a really common pattern when doing Boolean Algebra ... in my experience you have occasion to use it just as often as Absorption. So it has always been strange to me how few textbooks recognize this as an explicit equivalence and give it a name. So I just started calling it Reduction, and find it to be a super useful equivalence to have in my Boolean Algebra 'toolbox' :)
